# Gradle on Windows execute command

Tags: gradle

I try to create a Gradle task to drop and create a database on my development machine.

The commands are the following:

```
"c:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.3\bin\mysqladmin.exe" --user=dbuser --password=dbpass --force drop mydb

"c:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.3\bin\mysqladmin.exe" --user=dbuser --password=dbpass --force create mydb
```

And my gradle tasks are these:

```
task dropDB {
    exec {
        commandLine 'cmd', '/c', '"c:\\Program Files\\MariaDB 10.3\\bin\\mysqladmin.exe" --user=dbuser --password=dbpass --force drop mydb'
        ignoreExitValue = true
    }
}

task createDB {
    exec {
        commandLine 'cmd', '/c', '"c:\\Program Files\\MariaDB 10.3\\bin\\mysqladmin.exe" --user=dbuser --password=dbpass --force create mydb'
        ignoreExitValue = true
    }
}
```

My problem is that even if I execute only one tasks it seems both are executed. 
The output of executing createDB:

```
15:58:58: Executing task 'createDB'...

> Configure project :
Database "mydb" dropped

> Task :createDB UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
15:58:59: Task execution finished 'createDB'.
```

Please note the output contains **dropped** in the createDB task. And also if I call the dropDB task it reports that DB was dropped but I can still access it.

I'm using Gradle 5.4.1 on Windows 10 Home 64bit.

Comment: you are not configuring your tasks properly: the `exec` block will be executed during  `configuration` phase (so whatever task you will invoke, this will trigger execution of your `exec` block: just try with `./gradlew help` to observe).  See how to configure `exec` task properly here : https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html  (you need to declare your task with `type: Exec` )

Comment: see chapter 1 in https://blog.softwaremill.com/my-task-whats-wrong-with-your-gradle-task-82312100c595   (and all other chapters are worth reading as well ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to M.Ricciuti the working solution is this:

```
task createDB(type:Exec) {
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', '"c:\\Program Files\\MariaDB 10.3\\bin\\mysqladmin.exe" --user=dbuser --password=dbpass --force create mydb'
    ignoreExitValue = true
}
```